# Mongoose populate referencing object id, not the object itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

### Background

Here's part of my User model:

```js
const Group = require("./Group")

...

groups: {
    type: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: Group }],
    default: [],
},
```

And here's my Group model:

```js
module.exports = mongoose.model(
    "Group",
    new Schema(
        {
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                unique: true,
            },

            /**
             * Array of User ObjectIDs that have owner rights on this group
             */
            owners: {
                type: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: User }],
                default: [],
            },
        },
        {
            timestamps: true,
        }
    )
)
```

### The Code

Here's the code I'm running to try and populate:

```js
const user = await (await User.findOne({ _id: ... })).execPopulate("Group")
console.log(user.groups)
```

My console.log is outputting an array of *object IDs*, when I'd like it to output an actual Group document.

### Attempted solutions

I've tried changing my `ref` to be using the string (`"Group"`), I've tried arranging my query differently, etc. I'm not sure how I'd go about doing this.

Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate, I've done my best to search but can't really find a solution that works for me.

### Specifically, what do I need help with?

I'm trying to create a 'link' between a user model and a group model. In my console.log, I expect it to output a Group document; but it outputs an object ID (which is how it's stored raw in the database, meaning that Mongoose isn't transforming it correctly)

Comment: Your problem is unclear to me. Could you clarify your issue, expected output and actual output?

Comment: @JairusMartin I'm trying to create a 'link' between a user model and a group model. In my `console.log`, I expect it to output a Group document; but it outputs an object ID (which is how it's stored raw in the database, meaning that Mongoose isn't transforming it correctly)

Comment: If you could please update your question your more likely to get a response from the community.

Comment: @JairusMartin Done!

Comment: looks like your question is related to how to `declare` a relation between two models so you can access associated models like user.groups.name.

Comment: To give you some more lingo you are dealing with an ORM or object-relational model. I am not sure what language (python maybe?) you are using, but typically you would declare your User model and then your Groups model. Then in each model you would declare whether the model has a one-to-many or many-to-many relation with the other model. Once you declare that you should be able to use your user.groups syntax after retrieving the model.

Comment: Can you show what is the value to the _id you are passing here `User.findOne({ _id: ... })`

Comment: @ShijilNarayan The ID is passed based on a HTTP request (specifically 'req.cookie.session' in express). I know that it's working since it pulls the user record, and *is* pulling from the groups value (although Mongoose is not transforming it to a Group class)

Comment: @JairusMartin Yes! I'm specifically trying to access data like a groups name from the user model.

Comment: @ElliottLMz Looks like mongoose calls it `populate`. Have you read over https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html? If so, can you do a variable dump of the user to see how groups is being classified? Once dumped put the output in your question for all to see.

Comment: `execPopulate` takes a callback as an argument or returns a promise.  Did you mean to use `populate('groups')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change `execPopulate` to `populate` like:

```
async function findUserAndPopulate(userId){
  const response = await User.findOne({
    _id: userId,
  }).populate('groups')


  console.log("response",response)
}
```

You got:

```
{
  groups: [
    {
      owners: [Array],
      _id: 5ecc637916a2223f15581ec7,
      name: 'Crazy',
      createdAt: 2020-05-26T00:31:53.379Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-05-26T00:31:53.379Z,
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  _id: 5ecc6206820d583b99b6b595,
  fullname: 'James R',
  createdAt: 2020-05-26T00:25:42.948Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-05-26T00:36:12.186Z,
  __v: 1
}
```

So you can access the `user.groups`

See the doc: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html